# signalling a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

How could I call a method that is inside a thread, from outside the thread.  In some circumstances b() will be called from a() but in some circumstances I would like to signal the thread to go to b() from outside of the thread.  I assume I could use the observer pattern to solve this problem but I am already using the observer pattern on this thread to do something else, unless it would be possible to use the observer pattern twice.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new clientThread());
t.start();

boolean someBool = false;
class clientThread implements Runnable{
     run(){
         a();
     }
     public void a(){
        while(!someBool){
            Object ob = in.readObject();
            b();
            //do stuff   
     }
     public void b() {
           while(true){
               Object ob = in.readObject();       
               //do stuff
           }
     }
} 

t.b();
```

Comment: You need some way to communicate with the code running on that thread and ask it to do work for you.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's unfortunate that @Keppil answer got deleted.  Just because a method bleongs to some thread/runnable class, it does not mean that it HAS to be called on the stack of that thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to your ClientThread instance:

```
ClientThread client = new ClientThread();
Thread t = new Thread(client);
t.start();

client.b();
```

Note:  it is not possible to 'call' another thread of execution, only signal it.  So, the OP question must reduce to 'How could I call a method that is inside a java thread object'.  So, @Keppil answer was not incorrect and should not have been deleted.

Comment: I guess the OP wants something like SwingUtilities.invokeLater(), or ExecutorService.submit(), i.e. a way to pass a piece of code to execute to another thread.

Comment: How could ExecutorService.submit() be applied to this situation ?

Comment: Martin your answer doesn't answer what i'm trying to do but I've added some more information, does my post now clarify what i'm trying to achieve ?